# Should the IPA of the word "conscious" be /ˈkɑːnʃəs/ or /ˈkɑːntʃəs/?

Tags: pronunciation

Ok, see the word "**conscious**" has the IPA /ˈkɑːnʃəs/ in the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/conscious?q=conscious)

However, when you listen clearly, you will feel like it should be /ˈkɑːn**t**ʃəs/ not /ˈkɑːnʃəs/.  So it should read /tʃ/ rather than /ʃ/.

In some other dictionaries, which use different transcription systems, they give the entry "ˈkän(t)-shəs" , for example in the [Merriam Webster online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscious). Here we see it with a /t/.

So, should the IPA for the word "**conscious**" be /ˈkɑːnʃəs/ or /ˈkɑːntʃəs/?

Comment: It probably depends on your accent.

Comment: I find these extremely difficult to differentiate, if at all, even when extremely carefully articulated.

Comment: Get enough IPA and you become unconscious.

Comment: I speak with a northeastern American accent and I definitely always say tʃ. That being said, this might vary regionally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**

When we move from a nasal consonant /m, n, ŋ/ to a /f, θ, s/ or /ʃ/, we often accidentally make a /p, t/ or /k/ between them. This is because our tongue is making some kind of /p, t, k/ articulation left over from the nasal sound while the nasal cavity is simultaneously blocked for the articulation of the following sound. Such consonants are called *epenthetic* consonants. They are rarely included in transcriptions for words in learner's dictionaries. However, they often are included in transcriptions of words in more highbrow dictionaries and, importantly, in pronunciation dictionaries.  In terms of guidance for learners it is probably best to aim for the version without the epenthetic consonant. If you happen to make one, fine. That's perfectly acceptable. It's quite easy to spot epenthetic consonants in such dictionaries as these optional/accidental consonants are usually in brackets within the word, or are written in superscript.

### Real Answer

**How we use our velums!**

If you look into your mouth in the mirror and breathe out through your nose, you'll see a flap of skin/tissue hanging down at the back there and meeting the tongue, closing off the back of your mouth. If you then say "Aaaah" like you would for a doctor when they're trying to look at the back of your throat, you'll notice it lifting up off the back of your tongue so that you can see the back wall of your throat, a bit like a curtain that's being raised. It's got a little punch ball thing on the bottom of it, which is your *uvula*.

The name for that curtain-like tissue is the *velum*, literally *veil* in Latin. It plays a very important role in human speech. It's main job is to direct air either through the mouth or nasal cavity, or both. When you're resting it assumes a kind of half way position so that air can leave your vocal tract through both the mouth and nose during normal breathing. But if you make a consonant sound, for example the sound /t/, it raises up, blocking off access to the nasal cavity so that air is directed into the mouth. For a normal, canonical /t/, while this is happening, the tongue blocks the exit of the air by creating a seal with your alveolar ridge (that's the little shelf like part of your mouth behind your upper teeth). There is then a rapid build up of air pressure behind this blockage and when we release the /t/, we hear plosion which is the effect of this pressurised air being suddenly released. We would not be able to create this build up of air behind the /t/ blockage if we didn't have a velum. The reason is that all this air would simply escape through the nasal cavity and out of our noses.

In contrast when we produce a nasal consonant, such as /n/, /m/, or /ŋ/ the velum is lowered and the air passes out through the nasal cavity giving the sound a characteristic metally resonance. This time the air is blocked from leaving the mouth by your tongue and it is forced instead to exit via your nose. If you make a long /n/ sound and suddenly close your nostrils with your fingers, you'll find that the consonant is suddenly stopped. When you make a nasal sound the air needs to escape through your nose. Importantly, in terms of the Original Poster's query, when we make an /n/ sound, specifically, the tongue is blocking the mouth at exactly the same point it does for /t/.

**/t/ Epenthesis**

When we speak our organs of speech are always anticipating sounds that are coming up a bit  later. The smooth transition from one sound to another inside words, or across word boundaries, requires (subconscious) forward planning and small adjustments to the way we make individual sounds. The velum in particular, is slow to get moving, and it often starts it's journey upwards to close off the nasal cavity quite early in the proceedings, sometimes giving a nasal quality to vowels, for example, before a nasal consonant. So, if you listen carefully to the vowels in the words "*hot*" and "*on*", you might be able to hear that the vowel in the second word has a nasal tinge to it that is missing from the word "*hot*". This is because the velum is already anticipating the /n/ in this word and is already lowering, thereby letting air out of the nasal cavity giving the vowel that characteristic twang.

Now in the words *conscious* (in British RP, /kɒnʃəs/ in Gen American, /kɑ:nʃəs/), we see the sequence /nʃ/. What happens in this sequence is this: The blade of the tongue comes up to make a seal with the alveolar ridge for the /n/ blocking air from leaving the mouth. Meanwhile the velum is lowered allowing the free passage of air through the nasal cavity. The air coming up from the lungs, prevented from leaving the mouth, exits through the nose. Then, as the /n/ segment draws to a close and the /ʃ/segment begins, the velum raises to block of the nasal passage, the very tip of the tongue comes away from the alveolar ridge and the tongue furrows so that a kind of channel is formed down the central ridge of the tongue. The air now blocked from leaving through the nose is forced into the mouth and through this narrow channel. As it passes through this narrow gap it causes turbulence in the air heard as voiceless friction. In other words we hear a specific type of hissing noise.

Notice that there are two entirely different things going on here. On the one hand we have the tongue manipulating the air flow in the mouth, and on the other we have the velum blocking off or allowing access to the nasal cavity. In an ideal world the tongue and velum would work in perfect harmony so that the velum would block of the nasal cavity at the exact moment that the tip of the tongue moved away from the ridge. However, what often happens in reality is that the velum blocks off the nasal cavity a split second before the tongue comes away. During this split second, the air is directed into the mouth and there is a build up of air pressure behind the blockage that the tongue was making for the /n/. When the tongue does actually come away from the ridge this air is suddenly released. What has happened here is that we have accidentally reproduced the exact articulation for a /t/ sound: blockage at alveolar ridge, build up of air pressure, sudden release. This accidental articulation of an extra sound in such words is called *epenthesis*. We often see epenthetic consonants appearing when we have a nasal sound followed by a voiceless sibilant consonant (for example /s/ or /ʃ/). So we might see the following pronunciations for these words:

- mince /mɪn**t**s/
- hamster /hæm**p**stə/
- angst /æŋ**k**st/

These examples show the insertion of an extra /t/, /p/ and /k/ respectively.

So far I have described the insertion of such epenthetic consonants as accidental. Perhaps *incidental* might be a better description. These words sound perfectly natural with or without the extra consonants and many native speakers won't be able to hear the difference either way. Over the years many epenthetic consonants have become integrated into the formal spellings of words.

Should dictionary transcriptions of words such as these include versions with these epenthetic consonants? It is a good question. For learners it is probably not a good idea to give all the different possible versions of a potential word in any case. It is just not helpful. There is also the problem that if, for example, one deliberately accentuates the /t/ in *mints*, this would still be widely recognised as an acceptable form of the word. However, if we strongly accentuated a /t/ in *mince* this would be an unacceptable form of the word for many speakers (this is despite the fact that these two words are basically homophones for the majority of us). So for this reason a learner is probably best seeing the canonical versions of the words.

However, normal dictionaries and pronunciation dictionaries are an entirely different matter altogether. Here is part of what the world renowned Professor John Wells has to say about epenthetic consonants in his blog [here](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/epen-t-thesis.html). The abbreviation *LPD* stands for the also famous *Longman Pronuncation Dictionary*, which is probably the leader in its field:

> > Mariano was correct to make the generalization that plosive epenthesis happens (for those who use it) when ANY nasal is followed by ANY voiceless fricative, though only in certain syllabification environments. In my 2009 posting I mentioned **fen(t)s, ˈkɒn(t)ʃən(t)s, ˈhʌm(p)fri, ˈgæŋ(k)stə** (*fence, conscience, Humphrey, gangster)*. So the nasal can be labial or velar as well as alveolar; the fricative can be any of **f θ s ʃ**.
> >
> > In the examples just given the nasal+fricative sequence (or cluster) is always word-final or followed in the next syllable by a weak vowel: that is, these are cases where, in my syllabification analysis (which I know some people disagree with), the nasal+fricative cluster is syllable-final.
> >
> > In LPD I do not allow for epenthesis in words where (in my analysis) there is a syllable boundary between the nasal and the fricative, e.g. ˌ**ɪnˈsaɪd, kənˈsɪdə** (*inside, consider*): I took the view that this absolutely blocks epenthesis.

**The Original Poster's question**

The long and short of this is that the Original Poster's suspicions are perhaps correct. An IPA phonemic transcription of the word *conscious* could be either /ˈkɑːnʃəs/ or /ˈkɑːntʃəs/ (RP: /ˈkɒnʃəs/ or /ˈkɒntʃəs/). This might be represented in a good dictionary as /ˈkɑːn(t)ʃəs/, where the bracket indicates that the epenthetic consonant may or may not be present.

---

**A note on phonemic transcriptions**

It has been mentioned in answers or comments on this thread that the transcription /ˈkɑːntʃəs/ should not be used with these slanty brackets. The assumption is that /ˈkɑːntʃəs/ is not a *phonemic* representation of the word. Presumably the thinking behind this is that there is no /t/ sound in the internal mental representation of the word. Although it is irrelevant, this is in any case probably a mistake, given that the most important representation here is one of sound not orthography. The fact that for many speakers some such epenthetic consonants are parts of the words concerned can be seen from the fact that such words are often misspelled using these very consonants (for example *hampster*). However, I think the premise here is misguided. A *phonemic* transcription of a word is a transcription which represents a pronunciation using specific symbols where each symbol represents a sound which if taken in isolation by a listener would be *identifiable as a specific phoneme* in that language. Now in the pronunciation of the word *mince* for example, there is often a sound which is clearly recognisable as an instantiation of /t/ by listeners. The fact that it is recognisable as this phoneme means that if we are giving a phonemic transcription of such a pronunciation of this word it is clearly a mistake to transcribe this as /mins/ and clearly correct to present it as /mints/. This is not a description of the quality of the sound and therefore no square brackets, [], are required. The transcription consists entirely of a representation of (all) the discernible phonemes in such an instance of the word.

Comment: ‘Velums’? Really? (I’d say _vela_, is that just me?) Also, I have to disagree with your last paragraph: a phonemic transcription is by definition not a transcription which represents _any_ pronunciation, because pronunciation never occurs at a phonemic level. Phonemic transcription represents _non-pronunciation_, and automatic, epenthetic consonants can only confidently be stated to be phonemic if other factors than their presence in pronunciation support their being so. [Square brackets] do not necessarily represent narrow pronunciation, but they do represent _pronunciation_.

Comment: I agree that a spelling "hampster" is evidence that the p is perceived by naive speakers and therefore ought to be regarded as phonemic for those speakers.  A pronunciation that is perceived by hearers and intended by speakers is phonemic (as I understand that notion "phonemic").  I noticed that in your short answer, you write " In terms of guidance for learners it is probably best to aim for the version without the epenthetic consonant."  The phonemic form is what is aimed at.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Re *velums* I refer you [here](http://www.memidex.com/velums+general-anatomy) for the different possibilities from a medical authority. Re the phonemic transcription, I think I need to make what I'm aiming at a bit clearer, but 'tis 2.30 here so will have to leave it till tomorrow. Am flagging! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ok, there seems to be an issue with the idea of a "pronunciation" here. When people do research to find out how people speaking a particular variety of a language speak so that they can put this info in dictionaries, one of the things they usually do is give the (various) "pronunciations" of the word. These different "pronunciations" are different only in terms of the phonemic inventory of the word. We don't describe the potential allophones of each segment, the different potential realisations of each segment ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... whereas I always use a schwa. So when a good dictionary gives the alternative "pronunciations" of this word they give your phonemic version of the word and mine. Notice that each pronunciation is given in using symbols specific to the transcription of, in our case, RP, English. So the 'R'-sound in "rat" is given as /r/, not [ɹ ]. In general it is inappropriate to use symbols that represent language specific phonemes within square brackets, [ ]. ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... Lastly, when people do this research, they record the *identifiable* phonemes. They have no access to meta representations. However, they can record those sounds identifiable as instantiations of a specific English phoneme. So  in one given"pronunciation" of *hamster*, ***hæmpstə***, the /p/ (sic) is given as an example of the English specific phoneme appearing in the word. Is it part of an individual meta-representation? Generally, using symbols specific to the transcription of English, it's only appropriate to use //, not [ ], especially if no allophonic info is given.

Comment: I don’t really disagree with any of that (except I don’t understand what “…whereas I always use a schwa” is a continuation of?), with the scare quotes around ‘pronunciation’. My main point was simply that pronunciation, by definition, is a matter of _sound_, and phonemes, by definition, are a matter of _non-sound_, i.e., mental meta-representations, and therefore saying that a phonemic transcription is a representation of a pronunciation is misleading. As for / / vs. [ ] and narrowness, it was the implied opposite of “This is not a narrow transcription and thefore no square brackets, [], …

Comment: … are required” that ruffled me: square brackets do _not_ necessarily imply a narrow transcription, they simply imply that what is being transcribed is _sound_ as observed, rather than meta-representations as deduced. Your example of [ɹ] shows this, because [ɹ], in narrow transcription, is _extremely rare_ in English speakers outside Ireland (and some parts of Scotland). When [ɹ] is used as the phonetic transcription of English /r/, it is _broad_ transcription, where a narrow transcription would have [ɹ̱ʷ], [ɻ̞ʷ], or any of the other, numerous variations that actually occur.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Point about schwa/kit is just that what we refer to as our pronunciations of the word contain different phonemes. We describe this in phonemes not the phonetic quality of the sound that we're actually producing, but what that sound realises in terms of phonemes. So when the OP asks about  whether /ˈkɑːntʃəs/ is a correct transcription for a pronunciation of *conscious*, it's not particularly helpful to say "Oh you don't mean pronunciation" - because that's exactly what they mean so long as we interpret "pronunciation" in the same way it was used in that last sentence there :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, re broad/narrow, I was being slightly sloppy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Right, erm, yes I've actually used that in the post. I see. I'll have to edit it. Will be a little bit later though ...

Comment: Ah, but the question doesn’t ask whether it’s a correct pronunciation—it asks whether it’s correct _IPA_, which can be either. I suppose that lies at the bottom of the ambiguity. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, that's probably it I reckon! I've had a little fiddle about, nothing drastic, but I think I've got round that particular problem?

Comment: Yes, I agree; though I still disagree that the t should be considered phonemic. The difference between _mince_ and _mints_ is precisely that the former **sometimes** (but not always) has a [t] (and a glottalised nasal), while the latter **always** does. Since nasal-to-fricative sequences nearly universally tend to phonetically develop automatic epenthetic stops, the presence of the [t] in a phonemic structure /mins/ is easy to explain; but how do you explain the difference between _mince_ and _mints_ if you assume them both to have the same phonemic structure /mints/?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Isn't that kind of a different issue? It seems that that's a question of whether a word has a fixed phonemic shape or not. There's all kinds of rules that will allow for the elision, intrusion or assimilation of segements within a word. So the phonemic output for a word may not always be the same even for the same speaker (i.e. what phonemes may be employed in the production of a word may vary). For some speakers the word *mince* will, I suspect, always have a /t/ in their metarepresentation as well as a [t] in their production ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... but I reckon we all have a phonological rule that allows for the intrusion of a /t/ in this environment. This is because we get  epentheses of /p/ and /k/ as well as /t/ - these are all acceptable given the right environment. However, we can't mix these up. An accidental intrusion of /k/ in the word *mince* would be unacceptable for everyone. So it can't be that these sounds are entirely unnoticed, it's that they're licensed for want of a better word. And given that we can't swap a [t] for a [k] here, they'd seem to have some phonemic value. That's my thinking anyhow :)

Comment: Well, no—that just shows that _t_ and _k_ are phonemes, which we already knew. You can’t swap a [t] for a [k] _anywhere_, because they are separate phonemes; that’s sort of the whole point of phonemes. Sure, an individual word can have different phonemic forms, even to the same speaker; but the fact that we can _always_, no matter which word, insert [ptk] in nasal-fricative sequences, but _never_ remove them in (phonemically) nasal-stop-fricative sequences makes it much easier to simply say the [ptk] is not there phonemically.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ok, so this discussion's getting interesting. I can't write anything right now, 'cuz I'm with company, but do you fancy [continuing this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24565/discussion-between-araucaria-and-janus-bahs-jacquet). I'll write something there later, if you're up for it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ok a) how about "*jinxed, prankster, hampstead, the Hamptons*" where the /k/ or /p/ are optionally subject to elision? (There is an issue with the suffix /s/ on its own which would prevent the elision of  /p, k, t/, but only because of a voicing rule which would create a voiced suffix violating the voicing of the underlying form).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... But I'm a bit confused re your comments about /p/ and /k/ being phonemes. If they're phonemes, shouldn't they appear in phonemic descriptions of these words? If you're saying they aren't in the underlying form of the word, then I might agree (though not necessarily). But I'd say there's a rule that licenses their insertion - otherwise if we put the wrong one in it should make no difference, so they exist in some phonemic form of the word. I don't necessarily agree that this process can't work the other way. I just think there are constraints (i.e. before an 's'-suffix)

Comment: @Araucaria I meant they're phonemes in the English inventory of phonemes, just not ones that are present in this word. In the _jinxed_ list, the surface plosive may be optionally elided (though not so for me, I admit), but the ‘clipped’ glottalisation on the nasal is not; in _mince_, on the other hand, the glottalisation is optional (in AmE even uncommon). The suffix /s~z/ is actually a good example: _stunts_ clearly has an underlying (=phonemic) /t/, which is equally subject to elision; but the resulting form retains the glottalised nasal and, as you say, voicing mismatch occurs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet writes "... phonemes, by definition, are a matter of non-sound".  You might be interested to know that not everyone agrees about that.  It strikes me as being a revival of the old glossematics "point in a pattern" idea, or stratificational grammar.  I think phonemes are sounds, heard sounds, remembered sounds, targeted sounds, but still sounds, characterized with the same categorial features as surface pronunciations.  Paul Postal wrote a book about this.

Comment: @GregLee Yes, that's very interesting. I'll have to  track down that Postal. Incidentally, I have a friend who studied something related during some research for his master's. It was about the fact that when we read words certain pathways in our brains become active, which are the same paths that become active when we *hear* those particular sounds. Interestingly, when learners read an English word the pathways that would get activated for the nearest kind of sound in the first language get activated. One effect of this is that, for example, in RP we have three phonemes associated with ...

Comment: ... 'O', /ɒ, ɔ:, əʊ/  and when learners came from a language with only one open back vowel, reading words containing any of these English vowels activated the same auditory pathway (my terminology's being made up on the hoof here) that would be activated if they heard that one vowel in their own language. So their brains looked a bit like they were actually "hearing" their L1 phoneme when they read. (They hadn't yet developed a special "pathway" for the new sounds, either in their listening or their reading, as it were). Erm, not sure how that relates exactly, but I think it does somehow!?

Comment: @GregLee Better just point out that I'm recalling reading that my friend told me about two or three years ago, so many of the details and terminology are doubtless a bit off.

Comment: @Araucaria, that book is Postal, Paul M. (1968). Aspects of phonological theory. New York: Harper & Row. ISBN 978-0-06-045248-3.

Answer (score 5):

Since you use slashes for the transcriptions, I assume you're asking about the phonemic form of "conscious", not the actual pronunciation.  Right?  (Because if you were asking about the pronunciation, the answer would be different.)

Assuming that's what you mean, I favor the phonemic form without a /t/, /ˈkɑːnʃəs/.  If there were a /t/ there, I think it would be glottalized (pronounced with closed glottis) in pronunciation, as the /t/ is in words like "inch" [ɪnt'ʃ].  However, I don't hear any [t'] in "conscious".

There could be a [t], though, since it's hard to coordinate the articulatory movements so that the nasalization and voicing of [n] end exactly when the tongue moves away from the alveolar ridge to make the following fricative.  If there is a [t], I'd explain that as due to an insertion process applying between the /n/ and following /ʃ/.

Comment: Right. And it works for the other consonant series: /ms/ is often [mps], and /ŋs/ is often [ŋks]. It's hard to avoid an internal stop if you're speaking at a normal rate.

Comment: As a side note (only a side note, side the asker’s choice of IPA implies (s)he’s asking specifically about American English), the missing glottalisation is quite commonly heard in British English, which might indicate that there’s a greater amount of phonemic (as opposed to mere phonetic) vacillation there between /ˈkɒnʃəs/ and /ˈkɒntʃəs/ than in American English. (Or perhaps not—the same vacillation is found in _prince_, _ham(p)ster_, _angst_ mentioned by Araucaria below, so perhaps it’s just that the automatic, epenthetic phonetic consonant is more likely to cause glottalisation in BrE.)

Answer (score 1):

Polling multiple dictionaries, only one transcribes it with a /t/:

ˈkɑːnʃəs
ˈkɒn.ʃəs
ˈkɑnʃəs
ˈkɒnʃ.əs
ˈkɒnʃˌəs
kˈɑnʃəs
kɒnʃəs
kɒnˈʃəs
kˈɑnʃʌs
kɒnʃʌs
ˈkɒntʃ.əs
ˈkɔnʃəs
ˈkɔnʃәs

Comment: Which dictionaries?

Comment: [Lexico Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/conscious). [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscious).  That's two fairly prestigious ones.

Comment: The OED has just these two very simple pronunciations: *Brit.* **/ˈkɒnʃəs/**, *U.S.* **/ˈkɑnʃəs/**. No length markers, no affricates, no /t/, just a bit of rounding so that the UK version has the CLOTH vowel not the FATHER vowel as is more common in the States. (Note that some American speakers actually do have the same rounded vowel there that the Brits have. If you're looking for examples of this I'd first check speakers from Pittsburgh and Alabama.)

Comment: The one with the 't' was Longmans.