# What does () mean in IPA?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, dictionaries, parentheses, ipa

The [word expanse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expanse) in the Merriam Webster dictionary has this IPA transcription.

> ik-ˈspan(t)s

Does the () mean that the t is optional, or that it's very lightly pronounced? It would seem more logical that the parentheses indicate that it's optional, yet when I find the word in online recordings with a t, there is only vague traces of it.

Comment: The parenthesis is there also for the word "world", the Merriam Webster IPA is /ˈwər(-ə)ld/

Comment: Guide to linguistic Conventions -Brackets- http://www.languagegeek.com/roman/conventions.html

Comment: The question could be whether it means optional in the sense of: in free variation among the population, indicative of a particular subpopulation not specified, its articulation is not perceptible so it doesn't matter, or some thing else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is predicated on a misconception. Neither do the conventions of individual dictionaries comprise a suitable topic for ELU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merriam-Webster does not actually use IPA (in IPA "expanse" is standardly transcribed as /ɪkˈspæns/, although /ɪkˈspans/ is another possible representation). Parentheses are not an official part of regular IPA. In this context, they indicate "optional" sounds, as described in this ["Guide to Pronunciation"](http://assets2.merriam-webster.com/mw/static/pdf/help/guide-to-pronunciation.pdf) from one of Merriam-Webster's dictionaries. Often the sounds are optional because the phonetic context makes it hard to hear the difference between the alternative pronunciations.

There is a good explanation of the optional [t] in the answers to the following question: [Should the IPA of the word “conscious” be /ˈkɑːnʃəs/ or /ˈkɑːntʃəs/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250728/should-the-ipa-of-the-word-conscious-be-%CB%88k%C9%91%CB%90n%CA%83%C9%99s-or-%CB%88k%C9%91%CB%90nt%CA%83%C9%99s)